# PHP, MySQL - can you distinguish between rows matched and rows affected?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a PHP-MySQL database processor that is somewhat intelligent.  When this processor decides it needs to make an update, I want to report if it was really successful or not.  I thought I could use `mysql_affected_rows`...

```
// Example:
// After running query "UPDATE mytable SET name='Test' WHERE ID=1"
$result = mysql_affected_rows();
if ($result >= 1) { /* Success */ }
```

If, for example, there was no row with **ID=1**, then `$result` would be **0**.

However, it turns out that PHP's `mysql_affected_rows` is the actual affected rows, and may be still be **0** if the row exists but `name` was already "Test". (The [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) even say this is the case).

If I run this in the command line, I get the following meta information about the query:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Is there any way for me to get that "Rows matched" value in PHP instead of the affected rows?

[**Edit**]: I should note that I know I can run a separate query, but I'd like to not do that, for the sake of performance.

Comment: I'm not offering a duplicate, but this might be of interest to researchers that are doing INSERT-or-UPDATE processes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787059/2943403

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html) for `mysql_affected_rows`:

> For UPDATE statements, if you specify
>   the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag when
>   connecting to mysqld,
>   mysql_affected_rows()  returns the
>   number of rows matched by the WHERE 
>   clause. Otherwise, the default
>   behavior is to return the number of
>   rows actually changed.

With **mysqli**, you can specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS using [mysqli::real_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php).

```
$db = mysqli_init();
$db->real_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname', '3306', null, MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS);
```

In **PDO**, the constant is named PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydatabase;host=myhost', 'username', 'password', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true
));
```

With the old and deprecated MySQL extension, you can specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS passing the value 2 as the 5th parameter for mysql_connect ([source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.constants.php#mysql.client-flags)).

Comment: This is great.  While it doesn't offer me a way to distinguish between the two (so I'm going to test it before accepting the answer) it seems to me to be the preferable condition in my case. Thanks!

Comment: The PHP lib is such a transparent wrapper over the MySQL C api lib, you really can read the MySQL docs for a better understanding of the PHP/MySQL api

Comment: @Vinicius,  If you set that option, it now **only** returns *"number of matched rows, not the number of affected rows"*. How can we access both *affected_rows* and *matched_rows*?

Comment: @Pacerier with `mysqli` you can use `mysqli_info()`, as mentioned in the other answer (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php). With PDO I'm not sure if there's a solution without making an extra query.

Comment: @ViniciusPinto, It seems like a hacky fix (due to the need to parse the string and such).

Comment: @ViniciusPinto, Dang, this question would have been solved if only there's some way to [change the behavior of `mysql_affected_rows` between different queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289475/get-number-of-rows-matched-by-update-query-with-php-mysqli/5289535#comment45417545_5289535). As of now, parsing the output of `mysql_info();` is the best solution if you have multiple queries that use `mysql_affected_rows` differently.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the function

```
$variable = mysql_info();
```

That function retrieves a string like this:

> Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0

You can work with strings functions on your variable to extract the substring with the number of rows that matched and you should have it!

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. You can also match em like that: `preg_match('/^\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)$/',$variable,$matches);`

Comment: Use `$mysqliObject->info` when using the newer `mysqli` extension.