# Get number of rows matched by UPDATE query with PHP mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The older mysql extension has the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` connection flag, but I couldn't find any equivalent for **mysqli**.

I have an `update` query and want to know how many rows its `where` clause *matched*, not how many were actually changed (as indicated by `mysqli -> affected_rows`).

The only way I've figured out so far is to parse `mysqli -> info` (which looks something like `Rows matched: 40 Changed: 40 Warnings: 0`) with a regex. But that seems hacky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's in the  options of  [`mysqli_real_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php).

Also introduced in PDO::MySQL in PHP 5.3.

Comment: Wonder how I missed that, I certainly thought I looked! Thanks.

Comment: Ah, yes, `_real_connect` is seldomly used, usually only by people wanting a specific timeout etc. :)

Comment: @Wrikken, If you set that option, it now **only** returns *"number of matched rows, not the number of affected rows"*. How can we access both `affected_rows` and `matched_rows`? Is there a setting we can modify while *halfway* through the connection?

Comment: @Pacerier: not that I'm aware of (but don't assume I'm right, never needed it). The documentation of [`ROW_COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) doesn't bode well for it. Of course, you can just `SELECT` (with an optional `COUNT(*)`) before an update, but this becomes a bit unreliable due to race conditions. However, depending on your transaction isolation level and the table engines involved you can get this reliable again, with _considerable_ overhead.

Comment: @Wrikken, Since a single statement alone is atomic, Why will there be race conditions?

Comment: @Pacerier: because what I'm saying is the (current PHP) driver does not give you the option to do it in one statement (both affected & matched). It would have to be 2 statements at minimum getting both those values. So, you have 1 `UPDATE` & `SELECT` statement, and unless you use the huge overhead of a [`SERIALIZABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_serializable) transation, or a locking `SELECT`, you aren't guaranteed the records remain the same between those 2 statements.\

Answer (score 7):

I used the following code:

```
// Parse the digits from the info string that has the following format:
// Rows matched: 0 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $mysqli->info, $m);
return $m[0][0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could run `SELECT COUNT(*)` with the same WHERE clause before running the UPDATE.  That will give you a count of the number of rows that would be matched.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?  This is a perfectly valid solution, doubly so if you're using transactions.

Comment: @Charles, Not me, but for something that **only requires one table query**, your solution has one query more. That's an unnecessary waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Also [`SELECT ROW_COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) can give the number of rows affected by update query.

Answer (score 0):

I did an explode function on the results returned from the info command and then took index[1].

```
$affected = explode(":", $connection->info);
$rowsAffected = $affected[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [official docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#104930), looks like this can be achieved by building the `PDO` object like this:

```php
new PDO($dsn, $u, $p, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));
```