# How to know MySQL update command has found the record or not?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Sometimes I need to know MySQL has found the record or no. I don't mean to know is there affected rows or not, just finding.

```
    $db = database_system::connect();
    $query = "UPDATE member SET username=?,password=? WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi",$this->username,$this->password,$this->id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if(!$stmt->affected_rows) throw new Exception("something about");
    $stmt->close();
```

For example, php code above will throw exception if there is no affected record, but I wanna throw exception when there there is no such user (with that ID).

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: by adding your where clause you are already checking whether the id exists or not.

Comment: Note: You are using `MySQLi_` not it's predecessor, might help if you declare that.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289475/get-number-of-rows-matched-by-update-query-with-php-mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check it in a separate query.  The number of affected rows can return zero if the details haven't changed, too. (i.e. updating a valid user ID with the same username & password as it was before)

So best run a separate select for the user, first.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an option to return the number of rows found, instead of the number of rows updated.

For PDO on PHP 5.3 and later:

```
$p = new PDO($dsn, $u, $p, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));
```

For MySQLi:

mysqli_real_connect($dsn, $host, $u, $p, $dbname, $port, $socket, MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS);