# PHP PDO retrieves row matches, changes values?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using mysql database in PHP via PDO as an interface. I need to get the values of row matched and changes of the table when I apply update or delete query. Let's say for example, I applied this sql statement

```
UPDATE user SET country = 'UK' WHEN country = 'United Kingdom'
```

I used `PDO::rowCount()` to detect the numbers of affected row. The problem is that if user (accidentally or intentionally) try to update the details by providing the same values (for eg.

```
UPDATE user SET first_name='Bob' WHEN first_name='Bob'
```

it returns 0 since it doesn't change anything to the database. But, if `first_name='Bob'` does not exist in the database, PDO still returning 0. I know I can use `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` to get numbers of matched row instead of numbers of affected row. But, i need both (matched rows, affected row or changes) to differentiate between if the record does not exist or if the query didn't update anything.

Is there any way to do it??

Is there any alternative to get the same info like `mysql->info` just like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289475/get-number-of-rows-matched-by-update-query-with-php-mysqli) with PDO??

Comment: show your code, you show nothing

Comment: You could run something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE first_name = 'Bob'` to retrieve the number of matches, then simply use your update script, and output the rows affected.