# affected_rows & updating mysql from php

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to update `mysql` from `php` with the same value as the existing one in the data then `affected_rows` returns zero. 
Which means the database operation went successful anyway. So I want to return the successful message, irrespective of the same value as before. but based on the `affected_rows` value I can't say anything. So in this situation how should i check that the operation was successful anyway?
The below will be an example case....

```
$query='update chapter set ChapterName=? where ChapterId=?';
$stmt=$mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt-> bind_param('si', $chaptername, $chapterid);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->affected_rows>0)
{return true;}
```

**EDIT** I have removed the typos.. that was my mistake

Comment: `if(condition) { do something } else{ do something else }`

Comment: @Fred-ii- ??? what do you mean?

Comment: as per your edit, you're doing that now, aren't you? I'm obviously not grasping the question correctly then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I believe they want rows matched instead of rows affected.

Comment: No @Uueerdo, the OP wants to know the number of rows affected by the update.

Comment: @JayBlanchard that would make the inclusion of "same value as the existing one" in the question irrelevant.

Comment: yes I want to know the rows matched..

Comment: that's a typo btw `if($smt`

Comment: Replacing with the *same value as the existing one* doesn't occur and therefore implies no success. It is nonsensical as only a negative number would be a failure.

Comment: @JayBlanchard that is exactly the problem in some cases though. Often, the rows matched is what is wanted, not the rows that actually change. I know from experience if you don't set that option on an ODBC connection, it can cause all sorts of headaches on MSAccess forms the use "linked" tables.

Comment: No doubt @Uueerdo, and a separate function would have to be used to determine what was matched. A 0 return of affected rows does not indicate success though. Perhaps the OP wants to look at `MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` in `real_connect()`. I've never used it with an UPDATE, so I don't know if it would return a match.

Comment: @whatever if `0` is returned that *is not an indication of success* because even if there is a match *nothing gets replaced*.

Comment: @JayBlanchard no I am not going for zero.. does my code say so??

Comment: That is your very first sentence @whatever Maybe you need to clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think you did not understand me.. I am saying that `affected_rows` return zero as usual if you try to update the field with same value as before..

Comment: OK - I understand that. What is it you want to do?

Comment: @JayBlanchard to check if the row matched in the database or not?? if it actually did not update, as the values are the same, but I want to notify the success message. so if do not get greater than zero value, I still want to display the success message because the operation reached to the row but did not deem it necessary to update..

Comment: Then look at `mysqli_real_connect` and `MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` as stated before. It will show 1 for a match and 0 for no match. Then you have to do a separate test for affected rows to see if a change was actually made. If match, success, if no match was there an update? Yes? Success.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Okay now I got it... writing the code first will have to check later so will employ this procedure then.. I asked early while I am writing code,  because the reset of the code was depended on this sollution.. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your connection method, there is usually a connection option to return matched rows instead of changed rows.

If you're using mysqli this might be the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5289535/4104224

This one looks a little more thorough and explicit though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925972/4104224

Comment: @whatever answer has been updated with links to specific answers that may help

Comment: yes checked it.. it will help me to narrow down now.. Thanks.. but not clear yet..

Comment: I figured since they were "internal" to stackoverflow, it would be safe; and would've felt like I was plagiarizing repeating it. Plus, I consider my first sentence the main answer as it applies more generally... and was given before the question was elaborated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach `affected_rows()` to the connection, not the statement:

```
if($mysqli->affected_rows >= 1) {
    // success
} else {
    // failure
}
```

Comment: Plus their `if($smt` is a typo on top of that.

Comment: *Every once in a while the bait I throw in will get me some fish Ralph.* Thanks @Fred-ii-

Comment: and nothing like *free fish* too Sam!

Comment: No the code is just an example.. I did not run this .. I was writing the code but in the middle I recalled that actually what can go wrong so came here to ask the question... I was just paste it as example.. sorry for that other mess.. :(

Comment: ah, the plot thickens ^

Comment: hhhh.. @Fred-ii- so funny... what is the answers top statement saying.. did not get it.. Is the `affected_rows` a method.. :o

Comment: Yes, affected rows returns the number of rows affected by an UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE @whatever.

Comment: @whatever have a look at the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: I was following this link..  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php