# Detecting found rows in an update

Tags: php, mysql

I current have the following two queries:

```
UPDATE `forum_subscriptions` SET `unread`=0 WHERE `userid` = ? AND `threadid` = ?;
```

And:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `forum_subscriptions` WHERE `userid` = ? AND `threadid` = ?;
```

This feels suboptimal.

I know that I can use "affected rows" to find the number of rows that the `UPDATE` modified, but if `unread` is already zero then "affected rows" will be zero, even if a row was found.

The second query's sole purpose is to find if that row exists.

Is there a way to find out if the `UPDATE` query *found* a row, as opposed to *updated* a row?

Comment: `mysql(i)_info()` may be what you're looking for? [PHP.net Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-info.php)

Comment: sure it is. you want found rows, but the only thing mysql provides is affected_rows, which is rows that were found AND changed.

Comment: But I want rows found *but not necessarily* changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, MySQL - can you distinguish between rows matched and rows affected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925831/php-mysql-can-you-distinguish-between-rows-matched-and-rows-affected)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> For UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value by default is the
>   number of rows actually changed. If you specify the **CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS**
>   flag to **mysql_real_connect()** when connecting to mysqld, the
>   affected-rows value is the number of rows “found”; that is, matched by
>   the WHERE clause.

If you can live with having two separate connections (one for found rows and one for affected rows), then you can set up the connection as follows:

Using **mysqli**, you supply `MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` as the last argument (`$flags`) to `real_connect()`:

```
$dbh = mysqli_init();
$dbh->real_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'db', '3306', null, MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS);
```

Using **PDO**, you supply `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` inside the options array which you provide as the last argument of the constructor.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=database;host=host', 'username', 'password', [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true]);
```

Comment: Hm... but there are other places where I use `affected_rows` for the number of affected rows. Can't I have both?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm not sure but you may be able to change the connection flag after the connection has been set up, if using **PDO**: `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS, false)`

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a way to do this without modifying the behaviour of ROW_COUNT(). Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31901307/492983) to a similar question, here's what I've come up with:

```
SET @temp=0;
UPDATE `forum_subscriptions` SET `unread`=IF(@temp:=@temp+1,0,0) WHERE `userid` = ? AND `threadid` = ?;
SELECT @temp;
```